# How do connect a water supply to a 3/4-14 NPS faucet connector on my vintage tub?

Tags: plumbing, bathtub

I just bought a new Kingston CC8T1 faucet for my vintage tub which has been a mess for years. I bought the faucet on Amazon and now realize that it's really unclear how to actually connect this thing.

Here are the docs that come with it:
https://media.kingstonbrass.com/pdf/technical/install/kingston-brass-CC8T1-install.pdf
https://media.kingstonbrass.com/pdf/technical/parts/kingston-brass-CC8T1-parts-diagram.pdf
https://media.kingstonbrass.com/pdf/technical/specs/kingston-brass-CC8T1-spec-sheet.pdf

So I have a 3/4-14 NPS pipe that I need to connect to my old water supply. I have new supply lines, but they don't match up. How do I connect a 3/8" COMP supply connector to a 3/4-14 NPS?

[image: 3/4-14 NPS][image: 3/8" COMP]

Comment: The 3/8" compression fitting attaches to your shutoff valves. But you need a different fitting than the 1/2" FIP to connect to your faucet. Take your faucet to a plumbing store and they'll fix you up.

Comment: A hardware store may also have a rack of random parts, including thread adapters, at the back of the plumbing section. Bringing in the piece(s) you are trying to adapt is definitely a good way to be sure you get the right thing. (Without doing so I would never have realized that one part was sized and tapped to match the compression fitting thread despite not being a compression fitting...)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you probably need a 3/4 inch compression fitting to attach to your tub faucet.  Not sure what diameter supply pipe you have upstream; to fill a tub, having 1/2 inch would be better than 3/8 inch. In any case, to have a flexible supply line connecting to your tub faucet, you might look at water heater flexible supply hoses, then replace your existing shutoff valves to match the size of those, or put in an adapter just downstream of your shutoffs.